# Why children born in Moola, Ashlesya, Jyeshta and Maga Nakshtras (stars) are considered inauspicious?

Tags: belief, astrology, nakshatra

There is a saying that a child born in Moola, Ashlesya, Jyeshta, Maga is inauspicious. Is this properly explained in any religious books? This question is pursuant to astrology.

Comment: Hanuman is moola nakshatra, Lakshmana is Ashlesya… and so on.. the statement is like adding insult to devatha.. Child is form of god.. don't bring in your inauspicious thought and paint the new born..

Answer (score 3):

What you read/heard is only the partial truth.There are two more nakshtras which are considered equally inauspicious as per the "Gandamoola" concept viz-Aswini and Revati.

There are 27 [nakshtras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nakshatras) in all in Jyotish.Of them  6 nakshtras, 3 ruled by Ketu(viz-**Aswini,Magha & Mula**) & 3 ruled by Budha(viz-**Revati,Ashlesa &Jyestha**) are called "[Gandamoola nakshtras](http://www.komilla.com/lib-gandanta.html)".Birth in them are considered inauspicious.Infact,not only Moon,other Grahas are also supposed to give malefic results if placed in the "[Gandantas](http://www.komilla.com/lib-gandanta.html)".

> Gandanta is the junction points in the zodiac that a particularly
>   connected with times of soul growth. This is the position of the
>   zodiac where the where the solar and lunar Zodiac meet. These points
>   are at the junctions of Pisces (Revati)- Aries (Ashwini), Cancer
>   (Ashesha)- Leo (Magha), Scorpio (Jyeshta)- Sagittarius (Mula). They
>   are especially powerful in giving Karmic effects.

[What is a Gandamool Nakshatra?](http://www.premastrologer.com/gandmoolfaqs.php)

> There are 27 Nakshatras in Vedic Astrology; in the modern era most of
>   the astrologers count 28 Nakshatras including Abhijit Nakshatra. Those
>   Nakshatras which are ruled by Ketu and Mercury are known as Gandmool
>   Nakshatra. These are basically 6 nakshatras namely Ashwini, Ashlesha,
>   Magha, Jyestha, Moola and Revati.

One of the authentic Jyotisha text, [The Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](http://www.astrojyoti.com/bphspage1.htm) ,mentions that birth in these nakshtras are considered inauspicious.

> 1-4. The Venerable Sage said. **O Maitreya! Now I will describe to you
>   the circumstances, in which the births are inauspicious in spite of
>   Lagn and the Grahas being well disposed.** Although Lagn may be well
>   disposed, births will be inauspicious, if they take place on Amavasya
>   (last day of the Krishna Paksha), on Chaturdasi (14th Tithi), in
>   Krishna Paksha (dark half of the month), in Bhadra Karan, in the
>   Nakshatr of the brother, in the Nakshatras of father and mother, at
>   the time of entry of Surya in a Rashi, the time of Pata, at the time
>   of solar and lunar eclipses, at the time of Vyati Pata, **in Gandantas**
>   of all the three kinds, in Yamaghant, Tithikshaya, in Dagdha Yog etc.

Remedies include chanting the Janma Nakshatra mantras etc.

Comment: I think you should include the effects of birth in such nakshatra as I believe that's what the OP wants to know, in the current form, your answer looks like it is an extension of question.

Comment: I don't think so.... The Q asks why inauspicious? My answer "because they are called Gandamoola... " It is not at all clear to me that OP knows abt the concept of Gandamoola, Ganadanta etc... @ChinmaySarupria

Answer (score 2):

There is an Alwar born in one of this nakshatra.
Place   Thirumandangudi
Month   Maargazhi
Star    Kettai (Jyeshta)

Similarly we can find more examples of spiritual Giants born in these nakshatras.

So inauspicious has no meaning for devotees of God. We can always strive to make the children devoted to Vasudeva and that will take care of all such concerns if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where you heard this saying but it is far from true.

The [birth star](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/Nakshatra_radical/nakshatra_main_page.htm) is the star-group the Moon occupies at the time of the birth.

[Ashlesha](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/Nakshatra_radical/09ashlesha.htm) and [Jyeshtha](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/Nakshatra_radical/18jyestha.htm) are rules by Budha (Mercury). Budha is friendly to Chandra (Moon), although their nature are quite different. Budha is the intellect and Chandra is the emotion. Hence, there may be some conflict at times.

Also, Mula and [Magha](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/Nakshatra_radical/10magha.htm) are ruled by Ketu. Now, one might argue that Ketu is a spiritual planet and may give hardship in the material plane. Although, in that case, same logic should be applied to Rahu or Shani.

To sum it up, even if there is any inauspicious effect at all, it is a small part of a very big picture. When looking at all the dimensions of a chart, these combinations lose their relative value.

Comment: If you have further questions on astrology, you can ask them here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101512/vedic-astrology?referrer=WNGAY2D0NY672-MEPBo36A2

Comment: @Amit--It is given in the Kudumba Jodidam book itself. Even I am a Mula born--undergoing suffering from lifetime till date. Career path was disabled. Working in wrong place. Jyeshta, Aailya and Maga also I have friends and relatives. Not upto the mark. After reading in the book and seeing practically I put the question. Your calculation is based on astrology which is mathematical calculation. Benefits or problems cannot be told by any astrologer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan There are millions of people with these birth stars, some would be miserable, many would be happy, so thats wrong logic. Focus on the strongest planets in your chart.

Comment: what u say is true. But the weaker planets also cause turmoil.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan That is true. As I said, only with the help of the stronger planets can you deal with the weaker ones.

Comment: @Amit--Yes. At times the weaker planets viz  Saturn, Mars can beat stronger planets also by their placement position itself.